# How can I block all HEAD requests to urls that contain a substring on Apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, httpd.conf, apache2, block

A server I administer is being pounded with a poorly coded AWS-built bot that switches IPs constantly and appears to be stuck in a recursive encoding loop. The only consistent fingerprint I can see is that each request is only a `HEAD` request and each request appears to re-encode the previous one. So `http://someurl.com/?foo=%25bar` becomes `..%2525..` becomes `..%252525..` ... `%2525252525252525...x1000`.

Here's an example of the types of requests I see:

```
HEAD http://example.com/?foo=%25bar
HEAD http://example.com/?foo=%2525bar
HEAD http://example.com/?foo=%252525bar
HEAD http://example.com/?foo=%25252525bar
HEAD http://example.com/?foo=%2525252525bar
HEAD http://example.com/?foo=%2525252525...25bar (x1000)
```

So far I've been using Cloudflare firewalls to block each IP, but they keep switching IPs.

How can I simply block all HEAD requests containing a substring (say `%25252525`)?

I'm running `Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)`.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/forms/report-abuse

Comment: Submitted the abuse report. Thanks @MichaelHampton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using mod_rewrite in your .htaccess?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} HEAD
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} 25252525
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

That will block all HEAD requests with a query string containing "25252525". Obviously you can tune this more as you see fit!

Comment: Assuming I did that, would these requests still show up in my apache access_log? Because the request still happened. It was just handled with the rewrite. In other words, how will I know this is successful? Just hit the append a url with `25252525` to see what happens?

Comment: So far, that's exactly what is happening. I still see requests for `2525` and `252525` in my logs. But now all `25252525` (and more`25`s) are no longer being recorded in my logs. Looks to be successful. Thank you!

Comment: Of course!! If you want more control over logging though, you can redirect to rsyslog. With that, you have a great deal of control over log entries to discard. But it sounds like it's all under control now.